# Why is my playlist ID undefined when my app tries to save a playlist to my Spotify account?

Tags: javascript, spotify, jsonresponse

I am working on the [Codecademy Jammming project](https://www.codecademy.com/paths/web-development/tracks/front-end-applications-with-react/modules/jammming/projects/jammming-prj) and I have gotten everything to work correctly except that I am unable to save my playlist to my Spotify account. When I try to run the below code, for some reason I get an error and it tells me the playlistId is undefined.

```js
let accessToken;

const Spotify = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return accessToken;
    }

    // check for access token match
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    const expiresInMatch = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

    if (accessTokenMatch && expiresInMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      const expiresIn = Number(expiresInMatch[1]);
      //This clears the parameters, allowing us to grab a new access token when it expires
      window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
      window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const accessUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
      window.location = accessUrl;
    }
  },

  search(term) {
    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`, {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
      if (!jsonResponse.tracks) {
        return [];
      }
      return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => ({
        id: track.id,
        name: track.name,
        artist: track.artists[0].name,
        album: track.album.name,
        uri: track.uri
      }));
    });
  },

  savePlaylist(name, trackUris) {
    if (!name || !trackUris.length) {
      return;
    }

    const accessToken = Spotify.getAccessToken();
    const headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`};
    let userId;

    return fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {headers: headers}
    ).then(response => response.json()
    ).then(jsonResponse => {
      userId = jsonResponse.id;
      return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`,
        {
          headers: headers,
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({name: name})
      }).then(response => response.json()
      ).then(jsonResponse => {
        console.log(jsonResponse);
        const playlistId = jsonResponse.id;
        return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks`, {
          headers: headers,
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({uris: trackUris})
      });
    });
  });
  }
};
```

I've tried logging the jsonResponse to the console and I don't see an id property ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLT0H.png)). Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I compared my code to the code used for their version of the site and it looks to be pretty much identical. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any playlists under your Spotify account?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, it appears you are making a call to the wrong endpoint to create the playlist

`return fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists'`

Perhaps try the below based on the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/create-playlist/).

`return fetch(https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists'`